# JetBrains DataSpell how to show full output for Jupyter cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jetbrains-ide, dataspell

I recently tried using Jupyter via DataSpell and faced the following problem: I cannot preview the full text output of a Jupyter cell if it is larger than ~10 lines. E.g. on the screenshot below I print lines from 0 to 19 and only lines 10-19 are shown:

[image]

I have to scroll up to see the top lines or to manually change window size for this cell's output.

In default Jupyter Notebook interface, you can easily control the size of output cell via buttons "Enable/Disable Scrolling for Outputs":

[image]

Is there any similar possibility to configure the output size in DataSpell? It is very inconvenient to scroll or to change size manually every time.

I've found a YouTrack-related ticket, but maybe any other advices could help? I would be very grateful. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-2053/Enable-disabled-scrolling-in-output-cell